# Avoid passing in an instance of an object as a parameter when invoking a delegate method on the same instance?

Tags: c#, .net, scope, delegates

I have a class `Y` with a member variable of type `Action<Y, object>`. I assign a static method from class `B` to this delegate when I instantiate the class.

```
class Y 
{
    //Other data fields...

    public Action<Y, object> DelegateMethodMember { get; set; }
}

static class B
{
    public static void StaticMethod(Y y, object obj) 
    { 
        //Just an example of something I need to do.
        y.Something = obj.SomethingElse;

        //Here's what I would like to do, while also getting rid of my first parameter.
        this.Something = obj.SomethingElse;
    }
}

//Elsewhere in the program...

Y y = new Y();
y.DelegateMethodMember = B.StaticMethod;
```

Here's where my issue comes in. Later on in the program I want to actually call this method and I end up with this awkward double-usage of the object instance:

```
y.DelegateMethodMember(y, objectGoesHere);
```

The reason for this is I have to use `y` inside of this method but I can't use `this` because the scope of the method is `B` instead of the instance of `Y` that I'm invoking the method from.

Is there any way to, perhaps by manually binding the scope a la JavaScript, avoid passing in `y` as a parameter an instead simply use `this` or some other pattern within the method to access the members of `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, with a little manipulation...

```
class Y
{
    public Action<object> SomeDelegate { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public static void SomeMethod(Y y, object o)
    {
        //...
    }
}

var y = new Y();
y.SomeDelegate = (o) => B.SomeMethod(y, o);
```

Which you can call later like this:

```
y.SomeDelegate(new object());
```

Which will be called with `y` as the method variable.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thanks for the quick and easy-to-understand explanation.